# new to java,stuck on chapter 4 arrays

Tags: java

i am a beginner to java and i'm studying from Head First Java. in one example it gives the following code and asks for the possible output (given as: 14 1). what does m4a[x].counter do? what value do we get from it? thank you.

```
public class Mix4{
  int counter = 0;
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int count = 0;
    Mix4 [] m4a = new Mix4[20];
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 9){
      m4a[x] = new Mix4();
      m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter+1;
      count = count + 1;
      count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
      x = x + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
 }
 public int maybeNew(int index){
   if(index<5){
     Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
     m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
     return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Use your debugger to find out.

Comment: Does this code really come from a book? It's awful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `m4a[x].counter` doesn't do anything except get set to `1` each time. When you create a new object in the array:

```
m4a[x] = new Mix4();
```

the `counter` is set to 0.

```
int counter = 0;
```

So the immediately following line:

```
m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter+1;
```

is simply setting it to the value "0 + 1".

The first 9 elements in this array will have a `counter` value of 1, the other 11 will not have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an array of 20 Mix4 objects, and the array is called "m4a". m4a[x] is the Mix4 object in position "x" of the array, and m4a[x].counter is addressing that object's "counter" variable.

Answer (score 0):

`m4a` is  an array of type `Mix4` and `x` is an int.  , so `m4a[x]` is the particular `Mix4` that is indexed by `x`.

If `x` is 0, than `m4a[x]` is the zeroth `Mix4` in the array.  if `x` is 1, than it's the one after that, and so on.

now the Mix4 class has an element called `counter` which is accessed by `variablethatisaMix4.counter`

therefore

`m4a[x].counter` or to visualize it:  `(m4a[x]).counter` is the `counter` field belonging to the `x`th item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy and past the code properly ?? This is not an easy way of learning Arrays!

Comment: This is not an answer. This should go as comment.

Comment: can't comment on his/her post unless someone comments on my answer ... =\

Comment: Are you kidding me. There is `add Comment` link from where you can add comment to question.

Comment: No, I am not kidding you. I am quite aware of `add comment` link. My guess is you need certain points to add comments to questions o.O